# Delphi (Seattle) - Closing a dynamically created modal form causes access violation

Tags: forms, delphi, access-violation

**Summary:** 
one form (Loan Form) dynamically creates a modal form called DatePickerForm (when user clicks a specific button).
After selecting a date in the DatePickerForm, the user clicks on that form's 'Close' button: (a BitBtn) - this is what causes an access violation error.

**Details:**

The purpose of the reusable modal DatePickerForm is to provide users with a consistent way of entering dates in special circumstances. It will be used in multiple other situations - that is, if I get it to work as planned.

Exact error text is: "Project ABCD.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0060d0b1: read of address 0x00000000'."

The code compiles and the program works fine until step 4 below:

Run-time Process:

1. The user clicks on a button on the Loan form (**works**)
2. The modal form DatePickerForm is created (owner: Application), then shown. (**works**)
3. The user selects a date from the DatePicker control. (**works**)
4. The User clicks on the OK button (**fails**)
5. The DatePickerForm should close and we should return to the Loan form - but the error occurs instead.
6. The next step would be reading the date still on the DatePicker's form DatePicker control (the form still exists, it is just invisible at this point)

**My questions**:

*A) Should this work or am I using dynamic form creation incorrectly?*

*B) Is there a better way to achieve this?*

Any help will be appreciated.

John

**DatePickerForm code (complete):**

```
unit DatePicker_PopupForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TfmDatePicker_Popup = class(TForm)
      DTDatePicker: TDateTimePicker;
      lblDatePrompt: TLabel;
      btnOK: TBitBtn;
      procedure btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
      { Private declarations }
  public
      { Public declarations }
  end;

var
    fmDatePicker_Popup: TfmDatePicker_Popup;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfmDatePicker_Popup.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    fmDatePicker_Popup.CloseModal;
end;
end.
```

**Loan form - partial code (complete code is roughly 9700 lines long)**

```
unit LoanForm;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, ......, DatePicker_PopupForm;

    ...

    implementation

    ...

    procedure TfmLoan.btnSetDefaultClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       DatePickerForm := TfmDatePicker_Popup.Create(Application);
       DatePickerForm.DTDatePicker.Date := GD_ProcessDate;
       DatePickerForm.ShowModal;        
       dDefaultDate := DatePickerForm.DTDatePicker.Date;
    end;
       ...

  end.
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CloseModal) says:

> Do not call CloseModal in your application. CloseModal is used by the VCL when a modal form needs to be closed. CloseModal does not close the form by itself; it simply calls the registered close events and updates the ModalResult property.

So, do as it says. Close a modal form by setting the form's `ModalResult` property.

The easiest way to do that is to remove the button `OnClick` event handler. Instead set the button's `ModalResult` property in the designer.

Comment: Thanks David - that did it!!!! I will definitely have to study this further (I hate not understanding how things work).  Thanks - John

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error message that you are accessing a `nil` pointer. And the reason for that is because you are calling `CloseModal()` (which you should not be calling directly in the first place) on a global `fmDatePicker_Popup` object pointer that is not actually pointing at a valid Form object to begin with:

```
procedure TfmDatePicker_Popup.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fmDatePicker_Popup.CloseModal; // <-- fmDatePicker_Popup is not assigned!
end;
```

The reason `fmDatePicker_Popup` is `nil` is because in `btnSetDefaultClick()`, when you create your `TfmDatePicker_Popup` object, you are assigning it to a different `DatePickerForm` variable instead of the `fmDatePicker_Popup` variable:

```
procedure TfmLoan.btnSetDefaultClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DatePickerForm := TfmDatePicker_Popup.Create(Application); // <--
  ...
end;
```

`TfmDatePicker_Popup` shouldn't be relying on *any* external pointers to itself at all.  Since `btnOKClick()` is a member of the `TfmDatePicker_Popup` class, it should be using the implicit `Self` pointer instead:

```
procedure TfmDatePicker_Popup.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.CloseModal;
end;
```

Or simply:

```
procedure TfmDatePicker_Popup.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CloseModal;
end;
```

That being said, `CloseModal()` is the wrong thing to call anyway.  It doesn't actually close the Form, it just triggers the Form's `OnClose` event.  Per the [`ShowModal()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ShowModal) documentation:

> To close a modal form, **set its `ModalResult` property to a nonzero value**.

`ShowModal()` internally calls `CloseModal()` when it detects the `ModalResult` has become non-zero.  If the `OnClose` event handler sets its `Action` parameter to `caNone`, the `ModalResult` is reset to 0 and the Form is not closed.

So use the Form's `ModalResult` property instead, like the documentation says to:

```
procedure TfmDatePicker_Popup.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

Which can then be automated by removing the `OnClick` handler altogether and instead setting the button's `ModalResult` property to a non-zero value (or, in the case of `TBitBtn`, set its `Kind` property, which also sets its `ModalResult`).  When a button on a modal Form is clicked, it assigns its own `ModalResult` to its parent Form's `ModalResult` before triggering its `OnClick` event.

And then, you should also change `btnSetDefaultClick()` to look more like this instead:

```
procedure TfmLoan.btnSetDefaultClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  DatePickerForm: TfmDatePicker_Popup;
begin
  DatePickerForm := TfmDatePicker_Popup.Create(nil);
  try
    DatePickerForm.DTDatePicker.Date := GD_ProcessDate;
    if DatePickerForm.ShowModal = mrOk then
      dDefaultDate := DatePickerForm.DTDatePicker.Date;
  finally
    DatePickerForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy - thanks for the explanation. That is exactly what I needed to understand (I will have to spend some time thinking about it and experimenting before I feel comfortable using it with complete certainty that I am doing it correctly)